# jquery UI Autocomplete with stored list

Tags: jquery-ui, autocomplete

Hi I'm using jQuery UI Autocomplete and want do something like this: I want to get the list with AJAX when length=3 and this work great it populate the drop-down. Next I want when the length is >3 to use the returned list from the AJAX and filter it. But it give the same list not filtered.

```
$( ".selector" ).autocomplete({
            source:function(request, response) {
                var str_req = request.term;
                if(str_req.length==3) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/?search=1",
                        type: "GET",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: {term: request.term},
                        success: function (data) {
                            auto_data=data;
                            response(data);
                        }
                    });
                } else{
                    return response(auto_data);
                }
            },
            minLength: 3,
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                console.log( "Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.id );
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I would simply set the `min` to 1 and do a comparison in the `source`.

```
$(".selector").autocomplete({
  source:function(request, response) {
    var str_req = request.term;
    if(str_req.length < 3) {
       // Send your list back, if it was stored in 'myData'
       response(myData);
    } elseif(str_req.length==3) {
        $.ajax({
          url: "/?search=1",
          type: "GET",
          dataType: "json",
          data: {term: str_req},
          success: function (data) {
            auto_data=data;
            response(data);
          }
        });
      } else{
        response(auto_data);
      }
    }
  },
  minLength: 1,
  select: function(event, ui) {
    console.log( "Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.id );
  }
});
```

You could also do this as a Switch statement:

```
var str_req = request.term;
switch(true){
  case str_req.length < 3:
    // Send your list
    break;
  case str_req.length == 3:
    // Perform AJAX & return results
    break;
  default:
    // All other options
    response(auto_data);
}
```